# How to use Matlab function ordfilt2 to C++ with OpenCV

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, image-processing

I need to use the fuction of Matlab ordfilt2 in order to filter a noised image.

example of my code:

```
#include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int, char**)
{
Mat image = imread("C:\lena.bmp", 0);
Mat result = image.clone();
Mat final2 = image.clone();

if (image.empty())//check if empty
{
    printf("Image is not read! File is probably missing! Press any key to exim program");//message for error
    Sleep(10000); //10 second delay for showing message to user
}
else
{
    double value = 0.3;

    //printf("Give double for noise [0.00-1.00] :\n");
    //cin >> value;

    if (value >= 0.00 && value <= 1.00)
    {
        // imGray is the grayscale of the input image
        Mat noise = Mat(image.size(), CV_64F);
        normalize(image, result, 0.0, 1.0, CV_MINMAX, CV_64F);
        randn(noise, 0, value);

        result = result + noise;
        normalize(result, result, 0.0, 1.0, CV_MINMAX, CV_64F);
        imshow("Output image with noise", result);
        // I found this function (from OpenCV documentation) but I get syntax error
        dilate(result, final2, NULL, 1);

        namedWindow("Image blur", 1);
        imshow("Image blur", result);

        namedWindow("Original Image", 1);
        imshow("Original Image", image);

        waitKey();
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Wrong input! Try again!\n");
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

**EDIT** Matlab code:

```
x=imread('cameraman.tif');
x=Im2double(x);
sigma=20;
y=x+sigma*rabdn(size(x))/255;
z1=ordfilt2(y,3*3,ones(3,3));
z2=ordfilt2(y,1,ones(3,3));
z=1/2*(z1*z2);
Imshow(y,());
figure; Imshow (z1,());
figure; Imshow (z2,());
figure; Imshow (z,());
```

I have tried using dilate function, but with no luck.

I think ordfilt2 means order statistic filter. But when I look for it on the web, it seems I can't find anything usefull. All my attempts has fail so far, so, can you please help me?

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: Please provide how you're using `ordfilt2` in MATLAB.  You haven't specified what order you are using as well as the size of the window but you are correct.  It's an order statistics filter.  It sorts all of the values and with a specified rank, it outputs the value at that rank.  Starting from 1 which is the lowest value to `M` which is the largest value where `M` is the size of the neighbourhood.  Depending on what rank you're using, that will tell us how you can replace that call.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your reply,

I would like to use that function in order to filter my noised image with that specific way. In Matlab, we used ordfilt2, but with OpenCV and C++, it seems I can't figure out how to do the exact same thing. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: You still haven't answered my question. What is the exact way you are calling `ordfilt2`? There is no equivalent function in OpenCV but if you tell me what rank you're using with `ordfilt2` I can tell you which morphology operator you can use.... So please just answer my question.

Comment: If the OP reads how `ordfilt2` works from [here](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/ordfilt2.html), he can figure out which filter to use in OpenCV.

Comment: @rayryeng I edited my post and included Matlab code that I have and I need to do the exact same thing but with C++ and OpenCV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you are concerned about is here:

```
z1=ordfilt2(y,3*3,ones(3,3));
z2=ordfilt2(y,1,ones(3,3));
```

You are correct in that it is an order-statistics filter.  It specifically takes sliding neighbourhoods and outputs the desired **rank** of the window.  You have set this to be a 3 x 3 neighbourhood and the first line outputs rank 9, or the highest rank or highest value.  This is the local **maximum** and you can accomplish this with a dilation operator using morphological operations.  Similarly, the next line outputs the lowest rank, rank 1 or the lowest value.  This is the local **minimum** and you can accomplish this with an erosion operation using morphological operations.

You first need to use [`cv::getStructuringElement`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#getstructuringelement) to create the window that you want to operate one.  You basically want a 3 x 3 square, so you would use the `MORPH_RECT` property.  You would then use [`cv::dilate`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=dilate#dilate), then [`cv::erode`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=erode#erode) respectively.

Therefore, replace your current `dilate` line code with this:

```
//...
imshow("Output image with noise", result);

Mat se = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(3, 3));
dilate(result, final2, se);
erode(final2, final2, se);

//...
```

`cv::dilate` and `cv::erode` require **structuring element** to operate on for the third parameter.  Admittedly, you can specify `Mat()` as the third element which will operate on using a 3 x 3 neighbourhood by default.

You'll also want to change your `imshow` command to display the final image, not the intermediate one:

```
namedWindow("Image blur", 1);
imshow("Image blur", final2); // Change here
```